# Google Sheets: Row not copying to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two sheets. Pipeline and Archive. I also have a data validation list on column 5 that switches from blank to Yes only. When I debug it, it doesn't throw an error. But when I go to my sheet and change column 5 to yes, it doesn't move to the Archive sheet, nor does it delete anything.

```
function onEdit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c = s.getActiveCell();

if (s.getName() == "Pipeline" && c.getColumn() == 5 && c.getValue() == "Yes") {

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(c.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});
  s.deleteRow(c.getRow());

}

}
```

Comment: "it's not working" - what isn't working? The function doesn't run? It doesn't copy? It doesn't delete? It runs for every change? It runs for only certain editors? It copies to the wrong place? It only works every 4th Tuesday of the 8th week following a harvest moon? Edit your question to be specific about the error you are encountering, what you have done to resolve it, how that worked out, and so on. Respect our time, not just yours. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change:

```
    s.getRange(c.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});
  s.deleteRow(c.getRow());
```

To:

```
    s.getRange(c.getRow(), 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});
  s.deleteRow(c.getRow());
```

Hopefully this appeases the PTB...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19951013)

Comment: This is a stupid system.  If I want to help, I need 'reputation'.  But to get 'reputation', I need to answer questions.  When I attempt to help and gain 'reputation', by posting a FIX to an obvious problem, IN THE ONLY WAY THAT I AM ABLE TO DO, I get reprimanded and downvoted.  If SO would just let ALL users comment, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @RonKloberdanz I believe your original answer was phrased as a comment, hence the comments you received. Further, it is expected that the asker actually show effort and specificity when asking questions - they have provided no such thing yet, so providing an answer before then is only encouraging more low quality questions. It is good you are enthusiastic and want to help - just help those who show they value your time too.

Comment: I'm sorry about the undetailed question. This is my first time on StackOverflow. I've updated my question, but @RonKloberdanz answer was correct. I needed to updated 'sheet' to 's'. I can't believe I missed it! Thanks Ron for your help :)